# how to get only those records that have more than one values?

Tags: postgresql

```
ID           Matches
1000029049 335xxx219597989 
1000029361 335xxx217190890 
1000031383 335xxx219826131 
1000031433 492xxx6557366 
1000031433 335xxx216660374
```

I want to print only the ids that have different matches. 
E.g I want the below output.

```
ID           Matches
1000031433 492xxx6557366 
1000031433 335xxx216660374
```

Comment: Count `COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY id)` in CTE then select only those records where this field is not 1.

Comment: What if there was another row with e.g. `(1000031383, 335xxx219826131)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to group and join to the aggregation

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
  join (
    select id
    from the_table 
    group by id
    having count(distinct matches) > 1
  ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: i want the ones where id is same but matches is different., with above code : we are getting matches are same

Comment: @ArshiyaMukherjee: see my edit